# How to send fixed data with Iperf and measure bandwith?

Tags: ubuntu, iperf3

Is there a way to use Iperf3 tool sending 1GB of data and measure the bandwidth between server and client? I used the tool in the following way:

For the server:

```
iperf3 -s
```

For the client:

```
iperf3 -c <server ip>
```

I obtained the following data of the image, but what I want to measure is the time that takes to send 1GB of information from server to client. Is there a way to do this with Iperf?

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the -n flag to iperf3 to have it send a certain number of bytes, although we have noted some problems with the test stopping before all the data has been received.  We have a theory as to what the problem is (basically it comes down to the client telling the server "the test's done now" before all the data has been transmitted and received).  No idea what the fix should be, as of this writing.  But give it a try.  With a large enough test, it might not make a huge difference.

Answer (score 0):

Try using udp instead of tcp..... 
Use -u. Its available in the help

Comment: This looks more like a comment than an answer. Once you have sufficient reputation on this site you will be able to comment everywhere.